# ASP.Net Info Icon (asp:ImageButton)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an info image (asp:ImageButton), what I would like to do is, when the user clicks it, a small description window within the browser would show up as the following, what is the best way to do that?

[image]

This is my Image Button code:

[image]

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="~/img/Help-icon.png" runat="server" Height="30px" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click1" Width="30px" />
```

Comment: You really don't want a postback to the server so you'll have to do it with JavaScript.    Or, you could use the ToolTip property which will display the text on hover:   `ToolTip="Enter the 3-digit... "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/), [Kendo Tooltp](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tooltip/template) or similar one *(there are a lot of them out there*).

Actually, you do not want to use **asp:ImageButton** for that, because it will post back to server *(it is not what you want*).

Instead, regular html **image tag** can do the job.

***Note:*** If you really want to use server control, you can use **asp:Image** which won't  post back to server.